# Autofill with 2 variables in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set an autofill range with two variables in the range. It seems to work when there is one variable, but when I set it to 2 variables it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim Start Row As Integer
Dim End_Row As Integer
Start_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
End_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Range("D" & Start_Row).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:= Range("D" & Start_Row : "D" & End_Row)
```

The Error that I am getting is:

> Compile error: Expected: list separator or )

However, the code has no errors when I set it to:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:= Range("D:D" & End_Row)
```

So it seems to be an issue specific to when I put in the other variable

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `"D" & Start_Row & ":D" & End_Row` the `:` should be in the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Craner commented on your question, it is just that you are not correctly constructing the address string.

Say your `Start_Row` is `1` and your `End_Row` is `10`. What you want to pass to the Range function is: `"D1:D10"`

For the colon to be included in the string you send to the Range property, you need to build it as:

`"D" & Start_Row & ":D" & End_Row`

So your final code snippet would look like:

```
Dim Start Row As Integer
Dim End_Row As Integer
Start_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
End_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Range("D" & Start_Row).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:= Range("D" & Start_Row ":D" & End_Row)
```

This is quite a common mistake when referring to ranges in Excel, both in VBA and when using `Indirect` functions in Excel itself.